# Android - Managing Bitmaps from the web

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap

I am writing an app which displays images exclusively. It has a GridView of images, which displays at at most 10 images at any time on the screen. I found a tutorial about managing Bitmaps efficiently on the Android Developers website, but that seems to deal only with resource images. I want to know how to do this for images which I download from the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can download your image from the web and put it in the images folder of your app. Then, this image will be managed as the other resource images and you could use it as that.

Read the douentation here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: Hmm. How large a cache can I use for an app? I'm asking because my gridview is an endless-scroll view. It loads more images as we scroll down. Is this solution suitable for this situation too?

Comment: Please, read the android documentation here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html Apparantly, there is no size limit but you have to set the cache size. It's very good explained.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-load-images-from-web-and-caching.html

in the example, it is loaded only one image. but the same functionality you use in your adapter class for setting image in the getView().